# Is the behaviour of std::chrono::round on out-of-range values as intended?

Tags: c++, c++17, rounding, undefined-behavior, c++-chrono

I'm currently rounding a `std::chrono::duration<float>` to `std::chrono::duration<uint32_t>`, and when I give it out-of-range values it rounds to `1s` instead of `4294967295s`.

Looking at the standard, it says

> ```cpp
> template <class ToDuration, class Rep, class Period>   
> constexpr ToDuration round(const duration<Rep, Period>& d);
> ```
>
> [...]
> *Returns:* The value t representable in `ToDuration` that is the closest to `d`. [...]

Here is my exact code:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
        std::chrono::duration<float> seconds{std::numeric_limits<float>::max()};
        printf("float:    %f\n", seconds.count());
        printf("uint32_t: %u\n", std::chrono::round<std::chrono::duration<uint32_t>>(seconds).count());
        printf(" int32_t: %d\n", std::chrono::round<std::chrono::duration<int32_t>>(seconds).count());
        printf("uint64_t: %lu\n", std::chrono::round<std::chrono::duration<uint64_t>>(seconds).count());
        printf(" int64_t: %ld\n", std::chrono::round<std::chrono::duration<int64_t>>(seconds).count());
}
```

which outputs

```
float:    340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
uint32_t: 1
 int32_t: -2147483647
uint64_t: 9223372036854775809
 int64_t: -9223372036854775807
```

As you can see, other integer types also behave strangely. Unlike `std::lround` et al., `std::chrono::round` doesn't say anything about being undefined if the floating-point input is out of range.

Am I missing anything?

(For context, I compiled this with `clang` version `14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1` on x86_64, but I first noticed the issue on an ARMv7 system using `gcc`.)

Comment: Undefined behavior is, by definition, undefined.

Comment: Well I don't think this actually is undefined behaviour -- at least I can't see anything in the standard saying it's undefined.

Comment: It gets even weirder if you use a negative max-float value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`duration<Rep, Ratio>` is a simple, thin wrapper around `Rep`.  In your example `Rep` is `float` in the argument to `round` and `uint32_t` in the result.

As a thin wrapper, `duration` does not alter the fundamental behavior of the `Rep` for things like overflow and conversion.  To do so would add overhead when it is often not desirable.

If specific behavior such as overflow checking is desired, `chrono` facilitates that by allowing `duration<safe_int>` where `safe_int` is a hypothetical class type that emulates integral arithmetic but checks for overflow.  Real world examples of such libraries exist, and do **not** require special adaptation to be used with `chrono`.

For just `float` and `uint32_t` as asked about in this question, the undefined behavior results at the `float` and `uint32_t` and level, not at the `chrono` level.  [Specifically, when converting `float` to `uint32_t`, the behavior is undefined if the truncated value in the `float` can not be represented in the `uint32_t`.](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpint#1.sentence-3)

There is an open question as to whether the standard actually says this or not as discussed in the comments below.  To pursue this further, an interested party should submit an LWG issue:

http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue

And then the LWG will decide if there is a bug, and if so, how best to remedy it.

Pertinent links:

- http://eel.is/c++draft/time#clock.req-4.2
- http://eel.is/c++draft/numeric.requirements

Comment: But that's not what the standard says. It specifically says, "The value of `ToDuration` that is closest to `d`." It says nothing about using conversions. It specifically doesn't say "The value of `ToDuration` created by converting `d` to `ToDuration::Rep`."

Comment: In fact, "is the closest to `d`" means that it *can't* use float-to-int conversion, because that explicitly truncates the fractional part. But if you're converting 0.9 to an integer, the closest integer to 0.9 is **1**, not zero.

Comment: As a practical matter, there's nothing anybody can say here (including myself), that is going to add overflow checking under the hood of `duration`.  If you feel the standard is not clear in this area (and arguably it is not), the next best thing is to submit an LWG issue to clarify in a blanket statement that `duration` follows the behavior of `Rep`.  http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue. And I'm not sure how best to word that.

Comment: .9s rounded to 1s: https://wandbox.org/permlink/vctb3e06RyNOIsiV

Comment: If `chrono::round` is not required to follow the rules of [conv.fpint], then the UB provisions of that *also* don't have to be followed. Therefore, this is not undefined behavior as worded in the standard. Perhaps you want it to be and meant it to be. But the literal text of the standard says that bounds-checking for `chrono::round` is required.

Comment: So then, there is a bug in the standard.  There are currently 497 open issues (potential bugs) in the library section alone.

Comment: That's fine, but then your answer should be an acknowledgement that the standard says that this should work, but that the standard *shouldn't* say that.

Comment: Ok, done.......

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess that sort of confirms my suspicions ..
Though I just noticed another issue that I don't quite understand -- if I round a float duration 2^32-1 to a uint32_t duration, I get 0s instead of 4294967295s. `std::chrono::floor` appears to work correctly, unlike `std::chrono::round` though.

Comment: Ah, never mind about my last comment -- I was giving it 2^32-1 as a `float`, which of course isn't representable. So no surprise there ...

Answer (score 2):

According to the standard, the answers given by these implementations are incorrect. The standard text you cited makes it clear that this conversion must find the "closest" value to the input duration `d`. And 1 is not remotely the closest value to the maximum float, let alone any negative number.

The standard text for `chrono::round` does not require that `d` be within the range of the output `ToDuration::Rep`. Nor does it state that standard float-to-int conversions are at play (where out-of-bounds conversions are explicitly UB). Nor *could* they be used, since those conversions truncate the fractional parts, while `round` requires finding the closest value.

So calling `chrono::round` with this value clearly does not provoke UB.

*Should* the standard permit this in `round`? That's for others to debate. But as it stands, these implementations of `chrono::round` (and MSVC's too, in case you're wondering) are unequivocally defective relative to the actual wording of the standard as it currently stands.